# 100 strings in IN operator, oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, in-operator

I am passing 100 table_names in the IN operator as strings, but I am getting numeric overflow error due to too many operands. 
Is there a way where I can use something else besides IN ?

```
set serveroutput on

 DECLARE
  ...
 BEGIN
   FOR r IN 
   (
     SELECT table_name, column_name
     FROM all_tab_columns 
     WHERE table_name IN (...100 strings)
    )
AND data_type = 'NUMBER'
     ORDER BY table_name, column_id
   )
   LOOP
    execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT("' || r.column_name || '")
                             ,COUNT(nvl2("' || r.column_name || '", NULL, 1))                        
                       FROM "' || r.table_name || '"'
    INTO not_null_count, null_count;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(..)
```

Note: For variables I am using PLS_Integer.

Comment: As [the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52172), we can have up to 1000 values in an `IN` clause.  So that's not your problem.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting?  How are you passing your 100 strings to the query?

Comment: yeah, but this does not solve my problem

Comment: So answer my other questions.

Comment: error : numeric overflow error
        try reducing operands.

passing in a regular manner. 

where tbl_name IN('tbl1','tbl2',...'tbl100')

Comment: What error number?  ORA-01426?

Comment: I don't remember the error code, and don't have the access to the database right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested action for ORA-01426 is "reduce the operands".  This doesn't mean reduce the number of operands.  It means you're trying to put too large a number into a variable.  So shrink the number, or enlarge the variable.

You say:

> "for variables I am using PLS_Integer"

So, if you have a large table, and by large I mean more than 2,147,483,647 rows, you will get a numeric overflow.  Because `PLS_INTEGER` is [a 32-bit data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS319).

If this is your scenario then you need to declare your variables of data type `INTEGER` instead (or `NUMBER(38,0)`).

---

As @BobJarvis points out, PLS_INTEGER is optimized for hardware arithmetic.  So the general advice would be to use it for counting type operations.  However, your case simply requires a variable to hold the output of a SQL `count()` operation, so I don't think there will be any difference in efficiency.

Comment: I'm always a bit confused by PLS_INTEGER. In SYS.STANDARD we find `type NUMBER is NUMBER_BASE; subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38, 0); subtype BINARY_INTEGER is INTEGER range '-2147483647'..-2147483647; subtype pls_integer is binary_integer;`. Thus, it appears that PLS_INTEGER is a subtype of NUMBER (through several layers of subtypes). I imagine that the optimization to use hardware arithmetic is done behind the scenes.

Comment: @BobJarvis - it's interesting that `pls_integer` is of type `binary integer` when it is sort of the other way around.  Prior to 10g `binary integer` was implemented in platform-independent C libraries (like the other numeric datatypes); `pls_integer` was introduced (in 8.0 I think) with its more performant hardware optimization.  Then in 10g they converted `binary integer` to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limit on 'IN' clause is 1000 strings and not 100 strings. To debug:

a.) Try running your implicit cursor query in SQL.

b.) If it works fine then run the query in execute immediate after substituting the column name. 
Also , try increasing the size of your not_null_count and null_count variables.

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: Why "believe" something which you can verify in the documentation?  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52172)

Comment: for variables I am using PLS_Integer

Answer (score 0):

some other possible solutions

1. use a temp table - populate it with the table names to filter join to it.
2. create a global array type

   `create type table_of_varchar2 is table of varchar2(30)`

populate the array and filter using `table_name member of arr_tables_list`

Comment: This is solving the wrong problem.  Having 100 elements in an IN clause does not cause numeric overflow.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought i add some possibly relevant solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way where I can use something else besides IN ?

Consider using a cursor instead.